# Parsing dynamic lists in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to parse a JSON data making API calls that is a series of objects wrapped inside a list.

```
[
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "quidem molestiae enim"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "sunt qui excepturi placeat culpa"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 3,
    "title": "omnis laborum odio"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 4,
    "title": "non esse culpa molestiae omnis sed optio"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 5,
    "title": "eaque aut omnis a"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 6,
    "title": "natus impedit quibusdam illo est"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 7,
    "title": "quibusdam autem aliquid et et quia"
  },
]
```

And this is the widget on which I want the data to be rendered. I would also like to know if I have invoked the data from the json response correctly in the lines that I've commented :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../widget/list.dart';
import '../model/data.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MainScreenState createState() => MainScreenState();
}

class MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    // TODO: implement didChangeDependencies
    Provider.of<DataModel>(context, listen: false).fetchData();
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final provider = Provider.of<DataModel>(context).listData;
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Profile App 2"),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (builder, index) => ListWidget(
            provider[index].userId, //to fetch the userId
            provider[index].id,     //to fetch the id
            provider[index].title   //to fetch the title
          ),
          itemCount: provider.length
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The error now gets thrown against in the DataModel class at the lines commented 32:19 and 33:14:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class Data {
  final int userId;
  final int id;
  final String title;

  Data({
    required this.userId,
    required this.id,
    required this.title
  });
}

class DataModel with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Data> _list = [];

  List<Data> get listData {
    return [..._list];
  }

  Future<void> fetchData() async {
    final url = Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums');
    final response = await http.get(url);
    final extractedData = json.decode(response.body);
    print(extractedData);
    Map<String, Data> map = {};
    extractedData.forEach((value) => map.putIfAbsent(  //32:19
        value['id'], () => Data(                       //33:14
        userId: value['userId'],
        id: value['id'],
        title: value['title']
        )
      )
    );
    _list = map as List<Data>;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

The error:

```
E/flutter ( 9589): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String'
E/flutter ( 9589): #0      DataModel.fetchData.<anonymous closure> (package:profile_api_2/model/data.dart:33:14)
E/flutter ( 9589): #1      List.forEach (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:403:8)
E/flutter ( 9589): #2      DataModel.fetchData (package:profile_api_2/model/data.dart:32:19)
E/flutter ( 9589): <asynchronous suspension>
```

Comment: What is the current output and what do you want it to look like?

Comment: Sorry, my bad I didn't remember to post the error. Question now updated

Comment: The error message is saying what the problem is. You are trying to get `values` from the `DataModel` class, but that class doesn't have a `values` field. Presumably you meant to get `listData`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `_list = map.values.toList()`; instead of `_list = map as List<Data>` also now you have to use `provider[index].userId` instead of `provider.values.toList()[index].userId`.

Comment: I now get a new error in the DataModel class after applying the fix in the MainScreen class. The question is now updated

Comment: map.putIfAbsent("${value['id']}", ... or use Map<int, Data> map = {} instead of Map<String, Data> map = {}. I prefer  the  Map<int, Data> map = {} variant

Answer (score 1):

Change it to this:

```
final provider = Provider.of<DataModel>(context, listen: true);
.
.
.
.
//inside your listview builder, do this:

provider.listData[index].userId, //to fetch the userId
itemCount: provider.listData.length
```

Comment: I now get a new error in the DataModel class after applying the fix in the MainScreen class. The question is now updated

Comment: change this in your model: `title: value['title'].toString()`

Answer (score 0):

Please change datatype of your `id` or `userId` field of `Data` class. For some reason, it's unable to parse either `id` or `userId` as `int` or both. Please check by changing datatype to `String` one by one. Hope it will work.